# How do I bind a closure created inside a static function to an instance

Tags: php, binding, closures

this seem not to work and I don't know why?
you can create static closures inside non static methods, why not vice versa?

```
class RegularClass {
    private $name = 'REGULAR';
}

class StaticFunctions {
    public static function doStuff()
    {
        $func = function ()
        {
            // this is a static function unfortunately
            // try to access properties of bound instance
            echo $this->name;
        };

        $rc = new RegularClass();

        $bfunc = Closure::bind($func, $rc, 'RegularClass');

        $bfunc();
    }
}

StaticFunctions::doStuff();

// PHP Warning:  Cannot bind an instance to a static closure in /home/codexp/test.php on line 19
// PHP Fatal error:  Using $this when not in object context in /home/codexp/test.php on line 14
```

Comment: Hmm, doesn't seem to work with [`bindTo`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/closure.bindto.php) either.

Comment: From the bindTo docummentation "Static closures cannot have any bound object (the value of the parameter newthis should be NULL), but this function can nevertheless be used to change their class scope."  http://www.php.net/manual/en/closure.bindto.php , and since bind is just the static of bindTo i guess you can't make a non static closure on a static context.

Comment: This is fixed in PHP 7. See bugs [#64761](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=64761) and [#68792](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=68792).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As i said on my comment it seems that you can't change the "$this"  from a closure that comes from a static context. 
["Static closures cannot have any bound object (the value of the parameter newthis should be NULL), but this function can nevertheless be used to change their class scope."](http://php.net/manual/en/closure.bindto.php)
I guess you will have to make something like this:

```
    class RegularClass {
        private $name = 'REGULAR';
    }

    class Holder{
        public function getFunc(){
            $func = function ()
            {
                // this is a static function unfortunately
                // try to access properties of bound instance
                echo $this->name;
            };
            return $func;
        }
    }
    class StaticFunctions {
        public static function doStuff()
        {


            $rc = new RegularClass();
            $h=new Holder();
            $bfunc = Closure::bind($h->getFunc(), $rc, 'RegularClass');

            $bfunc();
        }
    }

    StaticFunctions::doStuff();
```